# I don't have access to foreach item from expression builder under data source in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to save some values in a SQL table and then loop over the values to use each value as path in an OData source.

First I have defined an array where to save the values:

[image]

then the variable is set to @activity('Lookup1').output.value

[image]

Now the data is accessed from foreach.
[image]

Inside the foreach loop I have a copy activity where the Odata source should be se as the value.
But I don't have access to the item. Why is that?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried just putting @item() in the expression builder to see if it works?

Comment: Dataset dynamic content don't have access to pipeline ForEach, thats why it is giving error while preview. But if you give @item() in it, it will work when you debug the pipeline. or you can create a parameter like above and it will show @item() for that parameter in the copy activity. In this case also, it will work when you debug.

Comment: Could you please clarify on this, you are not getting @item() in dataset dynamic content or pipeline dynamic content(inside ForEach)?

Comment: Using @item() in the path get " 'item' is not a recognized function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above approach will work for you when debug the pipeline even through it is giving warning in the dataset.

The dataset dynamic content doesn't know about ForEach `@item()` at first because it belongs to pipeline dynamic content. Thats why it is giving warning in the dataset.

But at debug time, it identifies the `@item()` value.

Please go through the below 2 scenarios to understand it better.

Here I am using ADLS as source and target with array of files for sample and passing to the ForEach.

These are my source files.

[image]

I have Created an array variable with above names like `["sample1.csv","sample2.csv"]` and passed to ForEach,

**Using @item() in dataset:**

Source dataset and target dataset.

[image]

[image]

**You can see it is giving the same warning, but it will give the correct result when you debug.** But in dataset preview, it will give the error.

[image]

Copied files to target successfully.

[image]

**Using @item() inside ForEach using dataset parameters:**

I have created the parameters and used in datasets.

**Source:**

[image]

**Target:**

[image]

Copy activity inside ForEach:

**Source parameter @item():**

[image]

**sink parameter @item():**

[image]

Files copied to target successfully.

[image]